# How do you store the text inputs from the Entry widget into a list?

Tags: python-2.7, tkinter

I've been trying to store it as a single string, let alone appending it to a list, by making a variable for it called "Whatisthisthing", but it's not working. Also, do you know why I can't use "Whatisthisthing" to replace Entry.get() with defining Showoncanvas?

```
import Tkinter
import random

master = Tkinter.Tk()

Entry = Tkinter.Entry()
Entry.pack()
Whatisthisthing = Entry.get()

Canvas = Tkinter.Canvas()
Canvas.pack()

def Showoncanvas(event):
    Canvas.create_text(random.randint(10,100), random.randint(10,100), anchor = "center", text=Entry.get())



Entry.bind("<Return>", Showoncanvas)

print Whatisthisthing


master.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 1):

An entry widget has an [`textvariable`](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/entry.htm) option in which the current text / content is stored. If you use a [`StringVar`](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/variable.htm) as the textvariable the content is automatically synched with this variable and can be read using StringVar's `.get()` method.

Since I do not have Python 2.7 installed on my system, I converted your code to Python 3 and used mentioned `StringVar` and its `.get()` method:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
# coding: utf-8

import tkinter
import random

master = tkinter.Tk()

Whatisthisthing = tkinter.StringVar()
Entry = tkinter.Entry(textvariable=Whatisthisthing)
Entry.pack()

Canvas = tkinter.Canvas()
Canvas.pack()

def Showoncanvas(event):
    Canvas.create_text(random.randint(10,100), random.randint(10,100), anchor="center", text=Whatisthisthing.get())

Entry.bind("<Return>", Showoncanvas)

print(Whatisthisthing.get())

master.mainloop()
```

The only differences between Python 2 and Python 3 should be the following:

- `Tkinter` --> `tkinter`
- `print` --> `print()`